# Converting exponential number from string to float (encoding issue?) Python

Tags: python

I want to calculate with a value in my dataframe, however, this string consists of an exponential number ('10⁻³'). Is this some kind of encoding issue? How can I convert this string into a float (e.g. 10e-3) so that can perform calculations with this value?

(using Python 3.8.8)

Comment: Please upload a concrete example of the problematic data, and what you expect it to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is to convert the Unicode symbols to something easier to work with.

```
import unidecode
simpler = unidecode.unidecode('10⁻³')
```

Now you can put an 'e' in front of any '-' or '+':

```
simpler = simpler.replace('-', 'e-').replace('+', 'e+')
```

Now you have a format you can give to `float`.

```
f = float(simpler)
```

Comment: This works assuming that the exponent has a sign, so it won't work for a string like `'10³'` e.g.

Comment: @kaya3 that's probably not the only shortcoming of this answer.  Until the OP fleshes out the question a little it's going to be hard to get a perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, that was exactly what I was looking for! And true, it might cause problems when there is no sign, but I don't expect the value to be positive at some point.